# Norm of a projection onto a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\alpha\leq \|u\|$  in an inner product space $V$,  is there a subspace of $V$ such that the norm of the projection of $u$ on it  is equal to $\alpha$?

Comment: Hint: What is the projection of $u$ onto a one-dimensional subspace spanned by a vector $w$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily, what you will need is a vector $v$ perpendicular to $u$ which is only guaranteed if the dimension is $2$ or larger (you also need $\alpha\ge0$. Then you can construct a $w$ (as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$) such that the norm of $u$ projected on the subspace $L_w$ spanned by $w$ is $\alpha$.

Let's say we have ortogonal unit vectors $e_u$ (parallel with $u$) and $e_v$ and let $e_w = e_u\cos\varphi + e_v\sin\varphi$ then we have that the norm of $u$'s projection on the space spanned by $e_w$ is

$$u\cdot e_w = u\cdot e_u\cos\varphi + u\cdot e_v\sin\varphi = |u|\cos\varphi$$

Just chose $\varphi$ such that $0\le|u|\cos\varphi = \alpha < |u|$